# Java: Login to url and download file

Tags: java, wordpress, authentication

How can I download file (java code) from url?
The issue is that I must be logged in to the site (the authentication is by wordpress)
Thanks

Comment: So you did nothing to accomplish this and just wait for us to come up with a solution, test it and post it for you to say *my work is done*? That's not how this site works.

Comment: I imagine Java has some sort of HTTP client object that you can use.  If the service in question allows authenticating on the actual request in question, you'd do that.  If authentication is itself its own step (which sounds like it's the case) then you'd use that client object to send the authentication request, retain the response in some way (a cookie, I'd imagine), and use that authentication token to craft the next request.  You may need to do some reverse-engineering in a browser debugger to see the actual requests/responses expected.

Answer (score 2):

There are various options you can use for this.

I suggest HTMLUnit.

1. Use HTMLUnit API - this has methods to login, passing the username and password.
2. HTMLUnit itself allows you to download file.